# How do I change the UI language on Padre?

Tags: perl, padre

I've installed the current version of Padre with Strawberry Perl for 64-bit Windows. My OS is in Portuguese, and the UI language of the Padre IDE is now Portuguese. How do I override the default and change it to English?

Comment: Was anyone else expecting a "teaching dad a new language" question?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

View -> Language on 0.60.

Err, Exibir -> Idioma.